# Is there a JQuery Map plugin

Tags: jquery

I need to show a map of the United States where each of the states is in a specific mode. When the user hovers over a state, I want to show a tooltip.

Does anyone know of a JQuery plugin that will enable this type of scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plugin provides this functionality:

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

---

If you don't mind using flash you could use Google Charts API as an alternative.
It contains various easy to use interactive map types.

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html

Answer (score 3):

Also not jQuery specifically, but you can try [PolyMaps](http://polymaps.org/) which has [various sample maps](http://polymaps.org/ex/), including [one that is exactly what you're looking for](http://polymaps.org/ex/statehood.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about jquery specifically, but I've personally used [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) in a similar situation and found it to be quite useful. You can see an example similar to what you want to do (I think) with the [Map of Australia Example](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two updated (and excellent) options:

http://jqvmap.com/

http://newsignature.github.com/us-map/

Comment: I can't seem to find licensing info for the second one.